# How to insert special character in text area in C# & ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to insert special characters in textarea of my ASP.NET MVC project but it cannot insert - I get an error

> Syntax error near this 't

Please help me find a solution so I can complete my project as soon as possible.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. You will need to provide more information: what special characters? What do you mean by "insert" and can you show that code? As edit to your post, please

Comment: It sounds like you are building a SQL statement instead of using parameters

Comment: As @HansKeﬆing says, this sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: use @ before the string start and you can add whatever string you want this will skip special characters.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to use parameterized SQL when handling input from untrusted source. It not only fixes the special character problem but also prevents [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into table_name(username)values(@username)", conn))
{                                                              
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is coming from SQL syntax, not from C# . You add the `'` it two times in a row to avoid the error

`select 'test's'` **error**

`select 'test''s'` **runs**